# Hypergeometric sum 3F2 at 1

Tags: hypergeometric-functions

Is there a closed-form sum for the hypergeometric series $_3F_2(a+c, c+d, 1; c+1, a+b+c+d \mid 1)$ where $a, b, c, d$ are all positive and not necessarily integers?

Update: The motivation for this question comes from equation 4 of this tech report on [random inequalities](http://www.johndcook.com/UTMDABTR-005-05.pdf). In some special cases, such as when one of $a, b, c$ or $d$ is an integer, the report gives a closed form sum.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to find a simple special case that Maple did not do directly,  I chose $a=0,c=1,d=0,b=2/3$.  The [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/) identified it, though:
$$
{}_3F_2\Biggl([1,1,1],\biggl[\frac{5}{3},2\biggr],1\Biggr) = \frac{\Psi^{(1)} \Bigl(\frac{1}{3}\Bigr)}{6} + \frac{\Psi^{(1)} \Bigl(\frac{5}{6}\Bigr)}{6}
$$

Comment: It is also $\dfrac{2}{3} \Psi^{(1)}(2/3)$. According to Wolfram Alpha, ${}_3F_2([1,1,1],[2,1+b],1) = b \Psi^{(1)}(b)$.

Comment: So ... if John does not think $\Psi^{(1)}$ is "closed form", then there is no hope for his general question. 

Answer (score 1):

According to Maple,

$${{\frac{\Gamma \left( c+1 \right) \Gamma  \left( a+b+c+d \right) 
G^{1, 3}_{3, 3}\left(-1\, {\Big\vert}^{0, 1-a-c, 1-c-d}_{0, 1-a-b-c-d, -c}\right)
}{\Gamma  \left( a+c \right) \Gamma  \left( c+d \right) }}}
$$
where $G$ is the Meijer G function.  But I don't know if you'd call that more "closed-form" than the original hypergeometric.

Comment: Thanks, though that's not what I'm looking for. A practical definition of "closed form" is "can be computed with commonly available software." That would include some special functions -- Gamma, Bessel, etc. -- but probably not Meijer G.

Comment: When you tell Maple to simplify that Meijer G expression, the result is the ${}_3F_2$ that you started with.  So (according to Maple) the Meijer G formula is less simple.

Comment: "Commonly available software" including Maple and Mathematica can compute the hypergeometric function.